# mobile battery charging using voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, charger, charging, mobile

Circuit shown at http://www.instructables.com/id/9v-USB-charger/ 
will that satisfy all condition of mobile charging through usb ?
what is advantage of circuit shown at http://electronicsproject.org/mobile-cellphone-charger/ over above ckt

Comment: Oh how instructable circuits make me shudder...

Answer (score 1):

The Instructables circuit is horrible and shouldn't be used.  It:

- has none of the required capacitors for the regulator.
- lacks the resistive dividers on the D+ and D- lines to make the phone enter proper charge mode
- runs off a battery with about 10% the capacity of a phone battery.

All in all the whole idea of the circuit is idiotic.

The other circuit seems to be aimed at directly charging a battery rather than supplying power to a device with a built in charge circuit (like a phone).  I'm not quite sure what they're doing with a 555 in there.

It certainly isn't suitable for connecting up to a 5V power input on a phone. It looks like it may blow the phone up.

To charge a phone from batteries you need:

- Regulated 5V power
- Enough current (500mA minimum)
- Enough battery capacity to get a decent charge
- For USB charged devices the D+ and D- lines require specific voltages on them to enter charge mode

Neither of those circuits provide that.

Comment: what happen with mobile or battery if I use Instructable's circuit ? and Why it will happen?

Comment: It may very slowly charge a little bit before the 9V battery dies.  The regulator will get hot.  Not much else.  That is if the phone allows it to charge without the D+/D- signalling.  It may just sit there doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A Li-Ion battery charging process consists of three stages:

•Pre-charging stage using current of 0.1C

•Constant current charging stage using current of 1C

•Constant voltage charging stage

NOTE: C is the battery capacity

Not following this steps may degrade battery and reduce its life

A lot of producer sells ad hoc IC for charging Li chemistry batteries. Have a look at Texas Instruments Website.